# JAVA declaring uninitialized JMenuItem() items inside JMenuItem[] constructor

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jmenuitem

I have this code:

```
JMenuItem itemA;
JMenuItem itemB;
JMenuItem itemC;
JMenuItem[] items = {itemA, itemB, itemC};
```

What I would like to do is declaring those JMenuItems inside the JMenuItem array constructor so I would spare several lines of else unnecessary code (that is get rid of that initial declaring of those separate items first). I would expect something in line of this fictional code:

```
JMenuItem[] items = {JMenuItem itemA, JMenuItem itemB, JMenuItem itemC};
```

...but that does not work, of course. Can anyone enlighten me how to do it, please?
BTW those items are initialized later in code.

Comment: @Abra did you read it where I said they are initialized later in the code? So yes, that is what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace this

```
JMenuItem[] items = {JMenuItem itemA, JMenuItem itemB, JMenuItem itemC};
```

with this

```
JMenuItem[] items = {null, null, null}; //option 1
JMenuItem[] items = new JMenuItem[3]; //option 2
```

Answer (score 4):

Declaring variables for the sake of declaring them is not necessary - declare them as close to where they are used as possible. Since you are not setting the visibility of `items` to `private` or similar, I assume that your code lives inside a method, probably a constructor for a window. In that case, I would recommend using (the spirit) of [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization): initialize & declare in the same statement. My code would look like

```
JMenuItem[] items = {
    new JMenuItem(openFileAction),
    new JMenuItem(saveFileAction),
    new JMenuItem(exitApplicationAction)
};
```

This assumes that you are using subclasses of `Action` or, even better, [AbstractAction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractAction.html) to supply labels, shortcuts, names, icons and `actionPerformed` code for each item. The advantage of actions is that they have much more memorable names than `itemA`, they can be called (and displayed) in several places (as buttons, as items, in multiple types of menus), and they can be enabled/disabled in all of them depending on the state of the application (for instance, `saveFileAction` can be disabled everywhere when there is no file to save).

Actually, I would go one step further. Since there is very rarely any need to change the menu once it is created, and you have access to their inner actions to enable/disable them, you can skip declaring `items` entirely:

```
JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
fileMenu.add(new JMenuItem(openFileAction));
// ...
```

---

Edit regarding how to define "everything in one go":

I prefer to use Actions to JMenuItems, as actions are more flexible (because they can be used in several places). You can give an action a label and its code in a single call, which is similar to what you could do with `JMenuItems`:

```
Action exitApplicationAction = new AbstractAction("Exit application") {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
      System.exit(0);
    }
};
```

However, having a home-brew subclass of `AbstractAction` (called `AllInOneAction` here) allows setting *everything* at once with minimal boilerplate (note that it is shorter and does a lot more than the above example!):

```
Action exitApplicationAction = new AllInOneAction(
   "Exit application", "exit.png", "Exit the program",
   KeyEvent.VK_E, "control shift E", () -> System.exit(0));
```

Internally, within that subclass, you would set a bunch of action keys:

```
public AllInOneAction(Object name, String iconName, String tooltip,
        Integer mnemonic, String accelerator, Runnable callback) {
    super("" + name); // allows your name to be an enum, useful for lookup
    putValue(Action.SHORT_DESCRIPTION, tooltip);
    putValue(Action.MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
    putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(accelerator));
    BufferedImage icon = loadImage(iconName); 
    BufferedImage small = scaleImage(icon, 16, 16);   
    putValue(Action.LARGE_ICON_KEY, new ImageIcon(icon));
    putValue(Action.SMALL_ICON, new ImageIcon(small));
    this.callback = callback;
}
```

Note that the implementation of `loadImage` and `scaleImage` is left as an exercise, but this is already a large-enough detour over the original question of "how to populate my JMenu".

Comment: Good points. Indeed one does not need variable for all JMenuItems, and can disable & hide& relabel  such menu items via there Action instead.

Comment: can we define item attributes (actionListener, setName) in "one go" if defined like you wrote `fileMenu.add(new JMenuItem(openFileAction));`, I would imagine somethig  like `fileMenu.add(new JMenuItem(){setName("some name");});` - is something like that even possible?

Comment: so short answer would be "No, it is not possible in the way I asked", sadly. But thanx for expanding your answer tho it is not what I wanted, cos then it has basically no difference in reducing code to the normal way of things like `fileMenu.add(openItem = new JMenuItem(MAINMENU_FILE_OPEN)); openItem.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {...});`. Furthermore your code actually seems much more complicated than this "simple" approach.

Comment: if you absolutely must use a JMenuItem (instead of an Action directly), this works: `fileMenu.add(new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("some name") {public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {System.exit(0);}}));`.

Comment: YES!!! This works beautifully - thank you very much (if this would be the merit of my question you would receive "correct answer" flag definitely)...so at least I click the up-arrow as your answer being useful - maybe you could even put this at the end of your post for others to find it easily!

Comment: if I can also ask you: is there a way to declare such item in the exact same way as you did above `setEnabled(false); setName("Some name")` so that I could somehow reference it (possibly) and make it disabled at start (would be enabled once the file is loaded - I have JAVA rendering application) - if not nevermind, I am just curious how far I can go with this

Answer (score 1):

You can initialise the array like this:

```
JMenuItem[] items = {new JMenuItem(), new JMenuItem(), new JMenuItem()};
```

And then use items[0], items[1], items[2] instead of itemA, itemB, itemC.